# Issue with a nested for loop

Tags: c, for-loop, nested-loops

I'm currently working on a program that asks a user to enter a secret word. The user's input is then compared with a list of words which are on a text file. The user has 3 chances to enter the word. If correct, the program restarts the loop. This continues until all the words have been guessed correctly. If a word is incorrectly guessed 3 times, the program should terminate. My problem is with the 3 guesses loop. I can get it to work if it is not nested in the `while` loop however with the `while` loop it's continues to ask for the incorrect word. What am I missing? Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
   //Step 1: open file and declare variables//
   FILE *fp;
   fp = fopen("secretwords.txt","r");
   char guess[20];
   char secret[20];
   int i;

   //Step 2: Check that file opened correctly, terminate if not//
   if (fp == NULL) 
   {
      printf("Error reading file\n");
      exit (0);
      fclose(fp);
   }
   //Step 3: Create loop to run for each word to run to end of file//

   while(fscanf(fp,"%s", secret)!=EOF)
   {         
      for (i=0; i < 3; i++)
      {
         printf("Please guess the word: \n");
         scanf("%s", guess);

         if (strcmp(secret,guess)==0)
         {
            printf("Your guess was correct\n");
            break;
         }

         else
         {
           printf("Your guess was incorrect. Please try again\n");
         }
      }   
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not do break in the following part:

```
else
{
    if(i == 2)
        break;
    printf("Your guess was incorrect. Please try again\n");
}
```

Comment: This is the exact code that works. I knew it was something relatively simple I just couldn't get my head around it. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3):

When you do `break`, you break from the `for` loop, but not from the `while` loop.

To solve it, you can either change the design to have one loop only, or you should have the `break` instruction in the outer loop too.

Comment: I had an idea that the break function wasn't correct I'm not entirely familiar with them. I basically want it so that when the user guesses the correct word the entire loop starts again but don't know how to format that.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if the user has had 3 misses, the value of `i` after the for loop will equal to 3. This is your chance to do something (terminate the program).